# Finding densities to estimate parameters using the Maximum likelihood technique

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, density-function, maximum-likelihood

Consider the  following autoregressive process with normal errors:
\begin{equation}\label{7YlUV4i8nuO}\tag{I}
    y_t = \phi y_{t-1}+ u_t, \quad u_t \overset{iid}{\sim} N(0,\sigma^2)
\end{equation}
We can show:
\begin{equation}
    y_1 \sim N\left(0,\frac{\sigma^2}{1-\phi^2}\right), \quad y_t|y_{t-1} \sim N\left(\phi y_{t-1}, \sigma^2 \right)
\end{equation}
Denote the density of $y_{1}$ as $f_{y_1}(y_1;\phi,\sigma^2)$ and the conditional density of $y_t|y_{t-1}$  as $f_{y_t|y_{t-1}}(y_t|y_{t-1};\phi,\sigma^2)$. Given $y_T,...,y_1$ a sample, the likelihood function, and the log-likelihood function are:
$$ L(\phi,\sigma^2) = f_{y_1}(y_1;\phi,\sigma^2) \prod_{t=2}^T f_{y_t|y_{t-1}}(y_t|y_{t-1};\phi,\sigma^2)$$
$$\mathcal L(\phi,\sigma^2) = \log f_{y_1}(y_1;\phi,\sigma^2) + \sum_{t=2}^T \log f_{y_t|y_{t-1}}(y_t|y_{t-1};\phi,\sigma^2)$$
[See here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/603410/marginal-distribution-of-an-autoregressive-process-of-order-one-ar1) to obtain the density $f_{y_1}(y_1;\phi,\sigma^2)$. For more details of all derivations, the reader can refer to this [note](http://course.sdu.edu.cn/G2S/eWebEditor/uploadfile/20140110134920017.pdf).

Now, I want to find the likelihood functions for a class of stochastic process with compound Poisson distribution, i.e., a generalization of [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution).  Given $N \sim \hbox{Poisson}(\lambda)$ with $\lambda\geq 0$ and $(y_t)_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ the AR(1) process given in (\ref{7YlUV4i8nuO}), define $x_t = \sum_{j=0}^{N} y_{t;j}$ (note that $N$ does not depend on $t$). It is straightforward to show that:
$$x_t = \phi x_{t-1} + v_t, \quad v_t:= \sum_{j=0}^{N}  u_{t;j}$$
where $(v_t)_t$ turns out to be white noise.

First, suppose the deterministic case $N=n> 0$ (If $N=0$, by convention $\sum_{j=0}^0 y_{tj} =0$ ) . Denoting $ \sigma_n^2 := n\sigma^2$, we have:
$$x_t = \phi x_{t-1} + v_t^n, \quad v_t^n:= \sum_{j=1}^{n}  u_{t;j}\sim N(0, \sigma_n^2)$$
Setting $\theta= (\phi,\sigma^2)$, we have that $x_1 \sim N(0,\sigma_n^2/(1-\phi^2))$, i.e, its denisity is:
\begin{equation}\label{2D85niRxr6}\tag{II}
f^n_{x_1}(x_1;\theta)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi \sigma_n^2/(1-\phi^2) }} e^{ -\tfrac{1}{2} x_1^2/\sigma_n^2/(1-\phi^2) }
\end{equation}
Moreover, we have that $x_t|x_{t-1} \sim N( \phi x_{t-1}, \sigma_n^2 )$, i.e., its density is:
\begin{equation}\label{2D85niRxr62}\tag{III}
f^n_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1};\theta)= \frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi  \sigma_n^2 }} e^{ -\tfrac{1}{2} (x_t - \phi x_{t-1} )^2/ \sigma_n^2 }
\end{equation}
In order to obtain the likelihood function for the random $N \sim \hbox{Poisson}(\lambda)$ case, first note that $x_1 = \sum_{j=0}^N y_{1;j}$ and since $P[N=0]>0$, we have $P[x_1=0]> 0$. That is, we have a mixed distribution (a density of a mixed random variable is neither discrete nor continuous) and this can complicate things a bit (Read this [post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362420/cumulative-distribution-function-or-density-for-compound-poisson-distribution) on this point). So, as a first exercise, let's assume that $N>0$. Setting $\mu  = (\phi, \sigma^2, \lambda)= (\theta, \lambda)$, we have that:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f_{x_1}(x_1|N>0; \mu)&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{x_1|N=n}(x_1|N=n;\mu)P(N=n)\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_1}(x_1;\theta) P(N=n)\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Analogously:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1}, N>0; \mu)&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{x_t|x_{t-1},N=n}(x_{t}|x_{t-1},N=n;\mu)P(N=n)\\
& = \sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1};\theta) P(N=n)    
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Thus, given $x_T,...,x_1$, the likelihood function is:
\begin{equation}\label{HK518fhA8lu}\tag{II}
\begin{aligned}
L(\mu| N>0)&=f_{x_1}(x_1| N>0; \mu) \prod_{t=2}^T  f_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1},  N>0; \mu)\\
&= \sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_1}(x_1;\theta) P(N=n) \prod_{t=2}^T \sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_1}(x_1;\theta) P(N=n) \\
&= e^{-T\lambda} \left[ \sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_1}(x_1;\theta) \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}  \right]  \left[ \prod_{t=2}^T\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1};\theta) \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\right]\\
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
The log-likelihood is
\begin{equation}\label{HK518fhA8lu2}\tag{IV}
\mathcal L(\mu| N>0) = -T\lambda + \log \left( \sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_1}(x_1;\theta) \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}  \right) +  \sum_{t=2}^T \log\left(\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1};\theta) \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\right)
\end{equation}
where $f^n_{x_1}(x_1;\theta)$ and  $f^n_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1};\theta)$ are respectively given by (\ref{2D85niRxr6}) and (\ref{2D85niRxr62}).

The general case is much more dramatic.
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f_{x_1}(x_1; \mu)&= \mathbf{1}_{[x_1 = 0]} (x_1) P(N = 0) + \mathbf{1}_{[x_1 \neq 0]}(x_1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{x_1|N=n}(x_1|N=n;\mu)P(N=n)\\
& = \mathbf{1}_{[x_1 = 0]}(x_1) e^{-\lambda} + \mathbf{1}_{[x_1 \neq 0]}(x_1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_1}(x_1;\theta) e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda} \left[\mathbf{1}_{[x_1 = 0]}(x_1)  + \mathbf{1}_{[x_1 \neq 0]}(x_1)\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_1}(x_1;\theta) \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\right]
%\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi \Tilde \sigma_n^2 }} e^{ -\tfrac{1}{2} x_1^2/\Tilde \sigma_n^2 }    
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Analogously, defining $D= [x_t = \phi x_{t-1}]$:
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
f_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1}; \mu)&= \mathbf{1}_{D}(x_{t}) P(N = 0) + \mathbf{1}_{D^c}(x_{t})\sum_{n=1}^\infty f_{x_t|x_{t-1},N=n}(x_{t}|x_{t-1},N=n;\mu)P(N=n)\\
& = \mathbf{1}_{D}(x_{t}) e^{-\lambda} + \mathbf{1}_{D^c}(x_{t})\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1};\theta) e^{-\lambda}\frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\\
&= e^{-\lambda} \left[\mathbf{1}_{D}(x_{t})  + \mathbf{1}_{D^c}(x_{t})\sum_{n=1}^\infty f^n_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1};\theta) \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\right]
%\frac{1}{\sqrt{ 2 \pi \Tilde \sigma_n^2 }} e^{ -\tfrac{1}{2} x_1^2/\Tilde \sigma_n^2 }    
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
Thus, given $x_T,...,x_1$, the likelihood function is:
\begin{equation}\label{26Y7lHzJ3}\tag{V}
L(\mu)=   f_{x_1}(x_1; \mu) \prod_{t=2}^T  f_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1}; \mu)
\end{equation}

I'm going to avoid making the respective substitutions so as not to load too many formulas and not write the log-likelihood function. So, I guess my questions boil down to:

1. Is there any way to try to find a more user-friendly form of the likelihood in (\ref{26Y7lHzJ3}) or the log-likelihood function for the general case? More specifically, how to find the $\hat \mu= (\hat \lambda, \hat \phi, \hat \sigma^2)$ that maximizes such functions?
2. If not, can we try to maximize the case $N>0$ given by $\mathcal L(\mu| N>0)$ above in (\ref{HK518fhA8lu2})? If we can't maximize directly, I thought about doing a truncation on $\mathcal L(\mu| N>0)$, i.e., finding $\hat \mu_M$ that maximizes
   \begin{equation}
   \begin{aligned}
   \mathcal L_M(\mu| N>0) = -T\lambda + \log \left( \sum_{n=1}^M f^n_{x_1}(x_1;\theta) \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}  \right) +  \sum_{t=2}^T \log\left(\sum_{n=1}^M f^n_{x_t|x_{t-1}}(x_t|x_{t-1};\theta) \frac{\lambda^n}{n!}\right)\\
   \end{aligned}
   \end{equation}
   Perhaps this maximization is feasible and with luck, I might have:
   \begin{equation}
   \hat{\mu}_M \longrightarrow \hat \mu = \hbox{argmax}_{\mu} \mathcal L(\mu| N>0), \quad (M \to \infty)
   \end{equation}
   If this is not a good strategy, what to do?

Comment: If $\xi_1,...,\xi_n$ are normal iid random variables, then their sum have normal distributuon but not with variance equal to $n^2\sigma^2$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Cumulative distribution function or density for Compound Poisson distribution](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362420/cumulative-distribution-function-or-density-for-compound-poisson-distribution)

Comment: Dear, thanks for the correction. I edited the question putting the sum variance equal to $n \sigma^2$. Thanks also for the suggestion. I am specifically interested in density, as some estimation methods use density rather than probability distribution.

Comment: What is $\ y_{t;j}\ $? Prior to the first appearance of this symbol, $\ y_t\ $ appears to have been defined as a real-valued random variable with no dependence on anything other than $\ t\ $. So what does $\ y_{t;j}\ $ mean?

Comment: In the context of Compound Poisson distribution (for stochastic process), $(y_{t,j})_t$ are iid copies of the AR(1) process $(y_t)_t$. Please note that this is different than the traditional Compound Poisson Process (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_process). What I'm saying is basically a generalization of this case(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution), where instead of compounding random variables, I'm compounding stochastic processes. Note that $N$ does not change over time.

Comment: $(y_t)_t$ is an autoregressive process of order 1. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Autoregressive_model The $(y_{t;1})_t$, $(y_{t;2})_t$, ..., $(y_{t;j})_t$,... are idd copies of $(y_t)_t$. Please tell me and it was clear.